# Zoom.us: increase FPS when sharing my screen

Tags: pulse-audio, zoom-meeting, fps

**TL-DR**: How can I make sure that zoom share my screen with FPS as high as possible?

I need to share some animated slides (some people will join physically, others remotely), where the animation helps to understand what is going on. For that reason, I'd like to make sure that everybody, including remote participants can see the animations with a good enough framerate (ideally 24fps).

Unfortunately, when I try zoom, I get a very poor FPS (like 1 frames per seconds maybe?). I made sure that `Meeting properties > Share screen > advanced > limit your screen share to XX frames per seconds` in unchecked, but this does not help. I can somehow get better FPS when I share my desktop using OBS + full screen projector, but it's not really ideal (I get maybe 5 FPS?)… Is there a more accurate way to share my screen with high FPS?

I also saw some people mentionning an option `Optimise  Screen Sharing  for  Video Clip`, but I can't find this option in my zoom (linux version). As it been removed? I also get an error "you need to install pulseaudio", but I'm using pipewire, and as I don't need audio share, I don't know if this is required:

[image]

**EDIT**

Actually, I realize by reading this [document](https://rps.org/media/itic1upy/optimising-your-system-to-show-avs-over-zoom.pdf) that audio share can't be decoupled from "optimize for video". So I installed pulseaudio packages (keeping pipewire for dealing with audio, I guess zoom just needs access to `pacmd` or similar), and now I've access to this when starting to share:

[image]

and the FPS is much better (with a bit more lag I think), even without OBS. However, I think that the resolution is now 720p, but it's not that important compared to video. I guess that my problem is solved!

Comment: @Rubén in the installable app. But if you tell me that it can be more reliable in the browser, I'm interested to learn more!

Comment: Regarding advanced customization / use, usually web apps are less reliable than the installable apps but I can't tell if this is the case for Zoom.